# Delay between API call to create GCP and creation

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm trying to write a script that will create a new google cloud project, then provision firebase resources to it, all using the Node SDK.

The first step is calling google.cloudresourcemanager("v1").projects.create, and I use an organization-level service account for that with the proper permissions which returns the proper Operation object on success.

The issue is that after this call, there's often a delay of up to several hours before a call to google.cloudresourcemanager("v1").projects.get or google.firebase({version: "v1beta1"}).projects.addFirebase works, and if you check in the console the project isn't there.  The issue is not with permissions (authorization/authentication) as when I manually verify that a project exists then call those two functions, they work as expected.

Has anybody else experienced something like this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the [Official API Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) it is mentioned this:

> Request that a new Project be created. **The result is an Operation which can be used to track the creation process.** This process usually takes a few seconds, **but can sometimes take much longer**. The tracking Operation is automatically deleted after a few hours, so there is no need to call operations.delete.

This means that this method works in an asynchronous way. As the response can be used to track the creation of the project, but it hasn't been fully created when the API answers.

Also it Mentiones that it can take long time.

As this is how the API works all the SDKs including the NodeJS one will share this behavior.